# Enforcing a rule in a symbolic expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems

I have already asked the [same question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151378-enforcing-a-rule-in-a-symbolic-expression) in the Matlab user community.

I have the following symbolic expression:

```
(3*s11)/2 + (3*s12)/2 + (3*s13)/2 + (3*s14)/2 + (3*s15)/2 + (s11*s12)/2 + (s11*s13)/2 + (s11*s14)/2 + (s12*s13)/2 + (s11*s15)/2 + (s12*s14)/2 + (s12*s15)/2 + (s13*s14)/2 + (s13*s15)/2 + (s14*s15)/2 + s11^2/4 + s12^2/4 + s13^2/4 + s14^2/4 + s15^2/4 + 9/4
```

It is stored as a symbolic expression variable. I would like to enforce the rule sij^2 = 1 i.e. the variables can be either -1 or +1. If I enforce the rule in the expression mentioned above, the expression will be as follows.

```
(3*s11)/2 + (3*s12)/2 + (3*s13)/2 + (3*s14)/2 + (3*s15)/2 + (s11*s12)/2 + (s11*s13)/2 + (s11*s14)/2 + (s12*s13)/2 + (s11*s15)/2 + (s12*s14)/2 + (s12*s15)/2 + (s13*s14)/2 + (s13*s15)/2 + (s14*s15)/2 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 9/4
```

How can I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set assumptions e.g. `assume(s14^2==1)`, then use `simplify`.